# Create table to store hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I want to create a table in SQL Server to store hours. User will select hours based on dropdownlist.

Monday: 8 AM to 5PM

Tuesday: 8:30 AM to 4:30PM and so on.

How can I store these and what is the datatype I have to use ?

Comment: Your description is insufficient for an answer. More details are important. e.g.: Which one database you use? How you want get this information?

Comment: @RenattoMachado It is sql server database. I tag sql. Its a free form for user to enter details when registering.

Comment: But it is not enough. The more information you put in, the easier it is to get an answer.

Comment: @WPFRookie your question is not clear. What have you tried? Perhaps you could provide a mockup of your idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering your ask, the datatype indicate for this type storage is `time`.

See in Microsoft Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx

**Would be something like this:**

[image]

Comment: I'm happy to have helped!

Comment: Storing a day of the week as a varchar is a waste. You should store the day of the week as a number (tinyint)

Answer (score 2):

TSQL code to create your table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_WeekHours(
    WeekHour_Id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,Week_Day VARCHAR(9)
    ,Start_Time TIME(7)
    ,End_TIme TIME(7)
)
```